# What does [Circular *1] mean (VS Code)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, circular-reference

Console.log of an object with a circular reference in vscode displays includes following snippet: "[Symbol(network)]: [Circular *1]".
I get why its circular, and I imagine the exact format is specific to VS Code but either way I would like to know more info - like what "*1" means.

Really surprised nothing comes up when I google '[Circular *1]'. What's the deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a number indicating which object it is referencing:

```js
const { inspect } = require('util');

const obj = {};
obj.a = [obj];
obj.b = {};
obj.b.inner = obj.b;
obj.b.obj = obj;

console.log(inspect(obj));
// <ref *1> {
//   a: [ [Circular *1] ],
//   b: <ref *2> { inner: [Circular *2], obj: [Circular *1] }
// }
```

Check out how each object have a `<ref *n>` which reflect on `[Circular *n]`.